# Symfony 4 - User management

Tags: symfony, roles, user-management

I’m using the latest Symfony 4 bundle with security package installed. 
As I use an admin page for my content I need to login of course and so I generated, how I learned it, an user and class entity with an `manyToMany` relationship.
This works well for creating a user and logging in and out, but unfortunately not for modifying a user.

I’m always getting an error about the roles as for edit the field is first not a role entity array entry but a simply array and so I can’t save the user.
There is no special user bundle or so installed.
When I delete the old entry from the database it works as there than exists no old value.

I also tried with `$userid->removeRole($roleRepository->findOneByLabel('ROLE_USER'));` at the beginning but than I also get an error that it must be an instance of the role entity.
Does anyone have any idea how I could resolve this? Or has an example code where I could check myself?

Comment: Tip: Create const for static params as 'ROLE_USER'. You can create those constants in user entity, so you can do this:

$userid->removeRole($roleRepository->findOneByLabel(User::ROLE_USER));

instead this:

$userid->removeRole($roleRepository->findOneByLabel('ROLE_USER'));

Answer (score 0):

I think for user manipulation this bundle is better. You can try.

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/integration/fosuserbundle.html